# VS2013 Test agent and controller not communicating

Tags: visual-studio, testing, azure, load, load-testing

I have a Windows Azure VM running VS2013 Load Test Controller and a second Azure VM running 2013 Load Test Agent.

I have not been able to get the two communicating successfully. I added the hostname and IP of each VM to the other's HOSTS file. I also created a local admin account with the same username and password on both machines. Neither machine is joined to a domain. I have also created endpoints for each VM to port 6901/TCP. I am able to telnet from the agent VM to port 6901 on the controller VM.

When I apply the test agent configuration settings, it fails on "Test agent could not connect to the test controller." In the agent configuration log, I see:

> Could not get the status from the test agent. Exception: Failed to
>   connect to an IPC Port: The system cannot find the file specified.

In the event viewer, I see:

> Unable to connect to the controller on 'controllerVM:6901'. The agent
>   can connect to the controller but the controller cannot connect to the
>   agent because of following reason: A connection attempt failed because
>   the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,
>   or established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond 168.62.XX.XX:6910. Make sure that the firewall on the test
>   agent machine is not blocking the connection.

I have been completely unable to work around this issue so far. I need help please.

Answer (score 4):

Can you Check your *c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts* file both agent and controler .
If there is an entry assigned to 127.0.0.1 remove that.

Comment: After 2 days of trying other stuff I finally tried this and it worked! tg

Answer (score 3):

When you install the Agent/Controller, be sure to use the same user (Admin) Account (Run as...). This account have to be in the group TeamTestAgentService on the controller.

In addition, after setup, the wizard will try to connect agent to the test controller. What's the status ?

MSDN explains [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh546459.aspx#workgroup) how to install/configure the test rig in a workgroup.

There is also a complete troubleshoot guide [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/df043823-ffcf-46a4-9e47-1c4b8854ca13/troubleshooting-guide-for-visual-studio-test-controller-and-agent?forum=vststest).